# Cannot read property 'jan' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I cannot get why my console gives me this:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jan' of undefined`

The function of this code, is to set var to 0, if it´s "undefined".

```
//Set months to loop/look for
var months = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","maj","jun","jul","aug","sep","okt","nov","dec"];

//GUL Loop threw result and create vars for each month
months.forEach(function (m){
  if (! result.GulAvformning[m]) {
    result.GulAvformning[m] = {};
    result.GulAvformning[m] = 0;
  }
});
```

I have this other code, and it doesn´t complain about this:

```
//BLÅ Loop threw result and create vars for each month
months.forEach(function (m){
  if (! result.BlåAvformning[m]) { console.log(result.BlåAvformning.jan);
    result.BlåAvformning[m] = {};
    result.BlåAvformning[m] = 0; console.log(result.BlåAvformning.jan);
  }
});
```

Result from console.log is:
`undefined`
`0`

What am i missing?

Comment: `result.GulAvformning` doesn't seem defined, but you don't show the relevant code

Comment: it's a bit strange to assign an empty object literal and then zero ...?

Comment: let me guess, your console is also empty? ;) And you are defining an array and using it as an object literal.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Tell me what you need!

Comment: We need information on where `result.GulAvformning` is supposed to come from.

Comment: @NinaScholz Weel, I´m using it for chart.js. Chart.js cannot handle undefined vars.. so therefore i need to set it to zero if it not exists. Why is this relevant?

Comment: Setting the property first to `{}` and then to `0` doesn't make much sense; the zero will just overwrite the empty object. It's not relevant to the error message, just superfluous.

Comment: The error message on the other hand means that `result.GulAvformning` doesn't exist.

Comment: We don't know what `result` is supposed to be. We don't know what `GulAvformning` is supposed to be. Perhaps you expect it to be there. Perhaps it *should* be there. Perhaps its not being there is an indication of a bug earlier in your code. Using the below answer will topically fix your error, but perhaps what you should really be fixing is the earlier bug in your code which causes `result.GulAvformning` to be undefined when it really should be defined at this point. That's why we were asking all those questions in the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you are showing the relevant code that popupates `result` object.

Assuming that `result` object is supposed to be populated here

```
months.forEach(function (m){
  if ( !result )
  {
    result = {};
  }
  if ( !result.GulAvformning )
  {
     result.GulAvformning = {};
  }
  if (! result.GulAvformning[m]) {
    result.GulAvformning[m] = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: @Mjukis thanks, but the information that `result` object was supposed to be populated here was missing from the OP. Maybe that is why people were asking for relevant code.

Comment: `result.GulAvformning = [];` it should be an object.

Comment: @NinaScholz Done, but I think it will work either way.

Comment: You may also want to get rid of the pointless `= {}` right before `= 0` while you're at it... :)